# How do I retrieve my Lost Solana from my Binance wallet

Tags: transactions

Am a novice in the crypto world. I sent 0.1 solana from Binance to my Metamask wallet and I can't find it there so I traced it to the bscchain and I found out it had been stucked so what can I do to recover it

Answer (score 1):

Sorry to hear you lost your funds. However, this website focuses on helping people who are developing software on Solana, so there's nothing we can do here.

You will have to get in touch with Binance support, maybe they can help you.